# Splash UI examples running in Docker

Tags: python, docker, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I've splash on windows running with Docker toolbox.

I am in Splash UI running a *built-in* example:

[image: Splash UI]

It seems correct but... it doesn't work!

[image: Error message]

Seem strange to me. Do you figure out why?

EDIT: same thing with
[image: Splash example 2]

output

[image]

Comment: Why did you tag your question with `docker` ?

Comment: I've splash on windows running with docker toolbox

Comment: Does it show the same errors when you try to run it locally (outside of your container) ? Do you have the correct version of your dependencies installed ?

Comment: No, because as is, you question is extremely unclear and doesn't provide enough details for us to help you

Comment: FYI, your issue is most likely due to either your docker configuration, which you didn't provide (try first to reproduce the issue outside of docker to confirm docker is causing the problem) or due to the way you configured splash ui, in which case SuperUser should be better suited as the question would not be code related

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49026524/edit) your question and add [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Providing code with images doesn't help SO users to recreate your problem.

Comment: I've answered thorougly explaining the errors, all non-related to docker. I think that this obsession with code written in plain-text and reporting lot of useless details is pretty crazy. I hope for you to never find the same type of downvotes in you questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors are due probably to legacy commands in the scripts. The first exemple works substituting the first instructions with

```
splash:set_viewport_size(800, 600)
splash:set_user_agent('Splash bot')
```

The second isn't working simply because of unsure javascript evaluation with `splash:evaljs` not permitted under the site policy.